# Wordpress backend post update without refresh

Tags: plugins

I regularly update large posts on my WordPress site let say more than 10000 words. Usually, I update paragraph by paragraph.

The problem, each time update the post while editing the backend getting refreshed and I need to start the post scroll from the beginning.

Is there a way, I can update the post without the page getting refreshed so that, i can stay in the point where I was without scrolling again from the top?

Comment: WordPress autosaves content for you on a regular basis. Would that work?

Comment: no. I check for formatting errors each time I update. So, autosave never gives the preview of actual formatting done.

Comment: I think the answer is no, unless you wanted to write something custom.

Comment: Well, one thing you can do is change to the Gutenberg editor. It doesn't refresh the page when you save (though it might have other downsides).